# Retrieve database records between two weekdays

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have several records in my database, the table has a column named "weekday" where I store a weekday like "mon" or "fri".  Now from the frontend when a user does  search the parameters posted to the server are  startday and endDay.

Now I would like to retrieve all records between startDay and endDay.  We can assume startDay is "mon" and endDay is "sun".  I do not currently know how to do this.

Comment: use numbers instead of "mon,tue..." that way you can just do a range call and get those. so if you put 1 as monday, 2 as tuesday, etc and want to get between monday and friday, you can just do a call where weekday is more than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 5. storing mon or tue or fri or whatever is very unintuitive if you want to aggregate data using those data

Comment: I agree, that seems to be much simpler, thanks :D

Comment: Will leave it open though, still need the answer, might need the solution later.

Answer (score 0):

Create another table with the names of the days and their corresponding number.  Then you'd just need to join up your current table with the days table by name, and then use the numbers in that table to do your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly practical, but it is possible to convert sun,mon,tue to numbers using MySQL.

Setup a static year and week number like 201610 for the 10th week of this year, then use a combination of DATE_FORMAT with STR_TO_DATE:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('201610 mon', '%X%V %a'), '%w')
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('201610 sun', '%X%V %a'), '%w')
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('201610 tue', '%X%V %a'), '%w')
```

These 3 statements will evaluate to 0,1,2 respectively.

The main thing this is doing is converting the `%a` format (Sun-Sat) to the `%w` format (0-6)

Answer (score -1):

well i don't know the architecture of your application as i think storing and querying a week day string is not appropriate, but i can tell you a work around this.
make a helper function which return you an array of weekdays in the range i-e

```
function getWeekDaysArray($startWeekDay, $endWeekDay) {
     returns $daysArray['mon','tue','wed'];
}

$daysRangeArray = getWeekDaysArray('mon', 'wed');
```

now with this array you can query in table

`DB::table('TableName')->whereIn('week_day', $daysRangeArray)->get();`

Hope this help

Comment: This does not even compile.